# How can I get the bitmap of the canvas I get in onDraw?

Tags: android, android-canvas

How can I create the bitmap from the canvas of custom view.

Comment: I just don't get why it was voted down...

Comment: @user940016 - your question shows no research, or any attempt to solve the problem yourself. read this for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way to extract the `Bitmap` out of a `Canvas`. The only way you can access it is to pass it yourself when creating the canvas like this `new Canvas(myBitmap)` and keep the reference.

EDIT2: see @Alex comment blow - the approach of passing a `Bitmap` to the `Canvas` does not seem to work for more recent versions of Android.

EDIT : If you don't create the `Canvas` yourself, you could create a screen-sized `Bitmap` (or whatever size you need) and then pass it to the `Canvas` in `onDraw` calls like this: `canvas.setBitmap(myBitmap)`.

Comment: But if I use onDraw, I get a canvas rather than creating it myself, so I don't have a reference to the bitmap...

Comment: If you don't create the `Canvas` yourself, you can not interact with its `Bitmap`. Calling `canvas.setBitmap()` in `onDraw()` causes `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: this may have changed in the last 3 years. The last time I tried was with 2.3 :) What is the version you have tried it with? And thanks for noticing, I will edit accordingly.

Comment: This approach won't work with a hardware accelerated canvas.

Answer (score 38):

While there is no `getBitmap()` function for a canvas, since you are making a custom view, what you can do instead is write a function like this inside your view class.

```
public Bitmap get(){
   return this.getDrawingCache();
}
```

This returns the Bitmap of the view, but it is important that in **all** your constructors you add this,

```
this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Otherwise `getDrawingCache` will return `null`

Comment: it will give always null object?

Comment: @sri - did you add `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` to the constructors of your view?

Comment: i have try you code but geting null.Any other solution?

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks a lot. Couldn't find this anywhere.

Comment: looks like `getDrawingCache` is being deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getDrawingCache()

Answer (score 2):

getDrawingCache() is deprecated in API 28.

So now you may use following code inside your custom view

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
draw(canvas);
// return bitmap; -- this is the bitmap you need
```

If you want to use this code outside your cusom view use methods like viewInstance.getHeight()... viewInstance.draw(canvas) will draw the view on the bitmap

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Canvas has a setBitmap function, but not a getBitmap one. It's strange, but anyway, it enables me to create the bitmap myself and pass it to the canvas, retaining the reference.