# Set canvas to imageview

Tags: android, canvas, android-imageview

I have a path drawn on a canvas as shown

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    path.moveTo(X, Y);
    path.lineTo(X+20, Y);        
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint); 
    invalidate();
}
```

I want this to appear in an imageView in an xml, but not sure how to do that.
How to I make this canvas appear in the imageview? I have a bitmap but unable to connect all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Path path=new Path();    
path.moveTo(50, 50);
path.lineTo(50, 50);
ShapeDrawable star =
     new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, 100, 100));
     star.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
     star.setIntrinsicWidth(100);
     star.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
     star.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
     ImageView iView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
     iView.setImageDrawable(star);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not extend the ImageView and override onDraw like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        path.lineTo(X + 20, Y);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
```

Here everything in `ImageView` will be draw in addition to your path.

If this is not what you want maybe this could be helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847728/how-can-i-get-the-bitmap-of-the-canvas-i-get-in-ondraw)

And calling `invalidate()` in `onDraw()` may be bad idea. It's recursive.