# Allow for Multiple-Pass Renders in GLSurfaceView Renderer with SurfaceTexture

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, glsurfaceview

I am displaying a video on a `GLSurfaceView` with a custom renderer that requires that multiple shaders be applied in succession. Currently, it is working successfully with one shader, though I am not sure how to extend the rendering pipeline to apply multiple shaders in succession.

I know that there are some examples concerning applying multiple shaders (using `FrameBuffers` and `RenderBuffers`), but I have not found any that deal with an image passed in through a `SurfaceTexture`.

There is a specific concern I would like to address:

A SurfaceTexture must be bound to a `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` texture. On the other hand, a FrameBuffer cannot be bound to a `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` texture (typically a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` is used), so is it even possible to use a FrameBuffer for a multi-pass render when the input texture is of a different format than the output? If not, what are the other options for performing a multi-pass render?

Below is some relevant code in the `onSurfaceCreated` function of the renderer I am trying to extend to perform multiple passes::

```
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, this.textureID, 0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, this.textureID[0]);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
            this.surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(this.textureID[0]);
```

Below is some relevant code in the `onDrawFrame` function of that renderer:

```
        synchronized (this) {
            if (this.updateSurface) {
                this.surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
                this.surfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(this.stMatrix);
                this.updateSurface = false;
            }
        }

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, this.textureID[0]);
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  //apply shader here and call glDrawArrays() at end
```

Comment: no single comment even?! it is funny that editors care more about making sure that u have not said thank you at the end or make a grammatical mistake in the question and don't care about such an important question. sof is becoming petty, soon it will die and stuff like chatgpt will take its place when they get a bit mature.

Anyway, @M.S. if u found the solution to this problem please share it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to use a [SurfaceHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder) rather than a SurfaceTexture.

From there, you can then get the [Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface) being held by the SurfaceHolder.

Then you can get the underlying [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) being drawn to.

Note: Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847728/how-can-i-get-the-bitmap-of-the-canvas-i-get-in-ondraw), you will need to use `setBitmap(Bitmap canvas_bitmap)` to specify the Bitmap being drawn into.

All the texture setup and parameter stuff will still need to be done basically the way you showed in you question.

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, this.textureID, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.textureID[0]);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Then dump the bitmap into a texture using:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, canvas_bitmap, 0 );
```

Comment: it is not possible to do that in my case, I need to use the TextureView as my cameraview which means I have to use the surfaceTexture. what I need is to understand how to convert from GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES to GL_TEXTURE_2D so that we can render external texture coming from the camera for example on a framebuffer @G. Putnam

Comment: to help you with that, I found a way but I can't understand how to do it, it is done using EGLImage and glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES and eglCreateImage. that is what I got so far maybe that helps u finding the solution

Comment: Ok, I was just trying to answer the question of "what are the other options for performing a multi-pass render?"  Another option that would support my answer would be [using a SurfaceView](https://tutorialwing.com/android-surfaceview-tutorial-with-example/) rather than a TextureView.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893367/how-to-show-the-camera-preview-on-a-surfaceview) also covers the topic.

Comment: sorry if it was not so obvious, my project has to use textureview and I am interested in knowing how to make framebuffer accepts to bound to a texture that is OES and not TEXTURE_2D, please help me if u can, and if u think it is impossible please let me know. I will give the bounty anyway.

Comment: If it must be TextureView and GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, then you could convert over to a GL_TEXTURE_2D using a method similar to [shown in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388939/read-from-gl-texture-external-oes-to-gl-texture-2d-have-perfomance-issues-and-gl) where you use glReadPixels to read to a buffer and then write to a tex_2D.  Note, from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258251/bind-gles-texture-to-gl-texture-2d-from-gl-texture-external-oes), it looks like if you use the GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES even in the main draw you need to have `samplerExternalOES`

Comment: Yeah regarding that one, glReadPixels is extremely inefficient and eats the whole gpu, keep in mind that I have 30 fps, so using glReadPixels, is not an option at all.