# OpenGL/Skia rendering GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES to GL_TEXTURE_2D

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-camera2, skia

I'm having a weird issue with my OpenGL/Skia Android Camera2 app.

My Camera renders frames into a `SurfaceTexture`, which is a `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` texture in OpenGL.

I can then simply render this OpenGL texture to all outputs (1920x1080 Preview `EGLSurface`, 4000x2000 Video Recorder `EGLSurface`) using a simple pass-through shader.

```
Camera --> GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES

GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES --> PassThroughShader --> Preview Output EGLSurface
GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES --> PassThroughShader --> Video Recorder Output EGLSurface
```

Now I want to introduce Skia into this, which allows me to render onto the Camera Frame before passing it along to my outputs (e.g. to draw a red box onto the Frame). Since I can't directly render onto the same `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` again, I created a separate offscreen texture (`GL_TEXTURE_2D`), and a separate offscreen frame buffer (FBO1) and attached them.

Now, when I render to the FBO1, the offscreen texture `GL_TEXTURE_2D` gets updated, and I want to pass that `GL_TEXTURE_2D` to my outputs then:

```
Camera --> GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES
GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES --> Skia to FBO1 + drawing a red box --> GL_TEXTURE_2D

GL_TEXTURE_2D --> PassThroughShader --> Preview Output EGLSurface
GL_TEXTURE_2D --> PassThroughShader --> Video Recorder Output EGLSurface
```

But for some reason, this draws the first frame only, then gets stuck and renders weird glitching artefacts on the screen. See video demo here:
https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/assets/15199031/254a5455-b9cf-4c1e-9cb9-85f9b60d0cd5

The relevant files are:

1. [onFrame(..)](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/cf8b37d3178ed81c4f764b6773e7b9e47504f9da/android/src/main/cpp/VideoPipeline.cpp#L103-L140): Called once the Camera put a new Frame into `_inputTexture` (`GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`).

   ```cpp
   // Camera texture
   OpenGLTexture& cameraTexture = _inputTexture.value();

   // Render to new texture using Skia
   auto newTexture = skia->renderFrame(_glContext, cameraTexture);

   // Reset the bindings
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, newTexture.id);
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, DEFAULT_FRAMEBUFFER);

   // Render to all outputs
   if (_previewOutput) {
     _previewOutput->renderTextureToSurface(newTexture, transformMatrix);
   }
   if (_recordingSessionOutput) {
     _recordingSessionOutput->renderTextureToSurface(newTexture, transformMatrix);
   }
   ```
2. [SkiaRenderer::renderFrame(..)](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/cf8b37d3178ed81c4f764b6773e7b9e47504f9da/android/src/main/cpp/skia/SkiaRenderer.cpp#L50-L131): Called to render the Frame onto an offscreen texture (`GL_TEXTURE_2D`) and add some additional Skia commands (draw a red rectangle).

   ```cpp
   if (_skiaContext == nullptr) {
     _skiaContext = GrDirectContext::MakeGL();
   }

   if (_offscreenSurface == nullptr) {
     GrBackendTexture skiaTex = _skiaContext->createBackendTexture(cameraTexture.width,
                                                                   cameraTexture.height,
                                                                   SkColorType::kN32_SkColorType,
                                                                   GrMipMapped::kNo,
                                                                   GrRenderable::kYes);
     GrGLTextureInfo info;
     skiaTex.getGLTextureInfo(&info);
     _offscreenSurfaceTextureId = info.fID;

     SkSurfaceProps props(0, kUnknown_SkPixelGeometry);
     _offscreenSurface = SkSurfaces::WrapBackendTexture(_skiaContext.get(),
                                                        skiaTex,
                                                        kBottomLeft_GrSurfaceOrigin,
                                                        0,
                                                        SkColorType::kN32_SkColorType,
                                                        nullptr,
                                                        &props,
                                                        // TODO: Delete texture!
                                                        nullptr);
   }

   GrGLTextureInfo textureInfo {
       // OpenGL will automatically convert YUV -> RGB because it's an EXTERNAL texture
       .fTarget = GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
       .fID = cameraTexture.id,
       .fFormat = GR_GL_RGBA8,
       .fProtected = skgpu::Protected::kNo,
   };
   GrBackendTexture skiaTexture(cameraTexture.width,
                                cameraTexture.height,
                                GrMipMapped::kNo,
                                textureInfo);
   sk_sp<SkImage> frame = SkImages::BorrowTextureFrom(_skiaContext.get(),
                                                      skiaTexture,
                                                      kBottomLeft_GrSurfaceOrigin,
                                                      kN32_SkColorType,
                                                      kOpaque_SkAlphaType,
                                                      nullptr,
                                                      nullptr);


   SkCanvas* canvas = _offscreenSurface->getCanvas();

   canvas->clear(SkColors::kCyan);

   canvas->drawImage(frame, 0, 0);

   SkRect rect = SkRect::MakeXYWH(150, 250, random() * 200, random() * 400);
   SkPaint paint;
   paint.setColor(SkColors::kGreen);
   canvas->drawRect(rect, paint);

   _offscreenSurface->flushAndSubmit();
   ```
3. [OpenGLRenderer::renderTextureToSurface(..)](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/cf8b37d3178ed81c4f764b6773e7b9e47504f9da/android/src/main/cpp/OpenGLRenderer.cpp#L46-L72): Called with the newly rendered to offscreen texture (`GL_TEXTURE_2D`) that contains the frame and the red rectangle. This will render the Frame to the output EGLSurface.

   ```cpp
   if (_surface == EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
     _context->makeCurrent();
     _surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(_context->display, _context->config, _outputSurface, nullptr);
   }

   // 1. Activate the OpenGL context for this surface
   _context->makeCurrent(_surface);

   // 2. Set the viewport for rendering
   glViewport(0, 0, _width, _height);
   glDisable(GL_BLEND);
   glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // <-- red for debug
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   // 3. Bind the input texture
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, newTexture.id);

   // 4. Draw it using the pass-through shader which also applies transforms
   _passThroughShader.draw(newTexture, transformMatrix);

   // 5. Swap buffers to pass it to the window surface
   _context->flush();
   ```
4. [PassThroughShader::draw(..)](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/cf8b37d3178ed81c4f764b6773e7b9e47504f9da/android/src/main/cpp/PassThroughShader.cpp#L28-L86): Actually doing the pass-through rendering of the 2D texture that contains my Skia drawing. [This](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/cf8b37d3178ed81c4f764b6773e7b9e47504f9da/android/src/main/cpp/PassThroughShader.h#L73-L81) is the shader that it uses. (`sampler2D` instead of `samplerExternalOES`, right?)

   ```cpp
   // 1. Set up Shader Program
   if (_programId == NO_SHADER || _shaderTarget != texture.target) {
     _programId = createProgram(texture.target);
     glUseProgram(_programId);
     _vertexParameters = {
         .aPosition = glGetAttribLocation(_programId, "aPosition"),
         .aTexCoord = glGetAttribLocation(_programId, "aTexCoord"),
         .uTransformMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(_programId, "uTransformMatrix"),
     };
     _fragmentParameters = {
         .uTexture = glGetUniformLocation(_programId, "uTexture"),
     };
     _shaderTarget = texture.target;
   }

   glUseProgram(_programId);

   // 2. Set up Vertices Buffer
   if (_vertexBuffer == NO_BUFFER) {
     glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
   }

   // TODO: I shouldn't be doing this each frame, but if I don't I just get a blackscreen.
   //   Maybe Skia is overwriting those values?
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VERTICES), VERTICES, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   // 3. Pass all uniforms/attributes for vertex shader
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(_vertexParameters.aPosition);
   glVertexAttribPointer(_vertexParameters.aPosition,
                         2,
                         GL_FLOAT,
                         GL_FALSE,
                         sizeof(Vertex),
                         reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(Vertex, position)));

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(_vertexParameters.aTexCoord);
   glVertexAttribPointer(_vertexParameters.aTexCoord,
                         2,
                         GL_FLOAT,
                         GL_FALSE,
                         sizeof(Vertex),
                         reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(Vertex, texCoord)));

   // TODO: Does this transformation matrix need to be applied before, in Skia already?
   glUniformMatrix4fv(_vertexParameters.uTransformMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, transformMatrix);

   // 4. Pass texture to fragment shader
   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
   // TODO: Do I need to use GL_TEXTURE0 here? Does Skia overwrite this value?
   glBindTexture(texture.target, texture.id);
   glUniform1i(_fragmentParameters.uTexture, 0);

   // 5. Draw!
   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
   ```

And the Shaders are here:

```cpp
static constexpr Vertex VERTICES[] = {
    {{-1.0f, -1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}}, // bottom-left
    {{1.0f, -1.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f}},  // bottom-right
    {{-1.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0f}},  // top-left
    {{1.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f}}    // top-right
};

static constexpr char VERTEX_SHADER[] = R"(
  attribute vec4 aPosition;
  attribute vec2 aTexCoord;
  uniform mat4 uTransformMatrix;
  varying vec2 vTexCoord;

  void main() {
      gl_Position = aPosition;
      vTexCoord = (uTransformMatrix * vec4(aTexCoord, 0.0, 1.0)).xy;
  }
)";
// TODO: This is NOT samplerExternalOES because we draw the TEXTURE_2D that Skia already rendered.
//    Is that correct?
static constexpr char FRAGMENT_SHADER[] = R"(
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec2 vTexCoord;
  uniform sampler2D uTexture;

  void main() {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord);
  }
)";
```

OpenGL setup is [here](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/cf8b37d3178ed81c4f764b6773e7b9e47504f9da/android/src/main/cpp/OpenGLContext.cpp#L51-L100), I basically have a 1x1 pbuffer for creating my textures, and then I switch between the output EGLSurfaces to render. When I render to the offscreen framebuffer (TEXTURE_2D), the 1x1 pbuffer is active.

I'm not sure if Skia is doing some texture/buffer binding that I should undo, if there is a memory issue, if the pass-through shader is wrong, or if the transformation matrix also needs to be applied to the Skia Shader.

If you want to take a look at this;

1. Clone this PR/branch: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/pull/1731
2. Run `yarn && cd example && yarn`
3. Open `example/android` in Android Studio

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Not an OpenGL developer but I noticed you didn't call `glTexImage2D` in `OpenGLContext::createTexture`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yea, I probably should add docs about that - the caller is responsible for filling the Texture if it's a 2D texture. If it's an EXTERNAL texture, you shouldn't use `glTexImage2D` because the Camera will fill it.