# How can I just use Surface View to only provide priview from Camera

Tags: java, android

```
<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"/>
```

I want to write a code in .java file where i just want to open camera inside this surface view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you need is to create an Custom Camera View
Here is the answer to that question
[How to show the camera preview on a SurfaceView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893367/how-to-show-the-camera-preview-on-a-surfaceview)