# Read from GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES to GL_TEXTURE_2D have perfomance issues and glitches

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, framebuffer, exoplayer

I'm need to send data from GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES to simple GL_TEXTURE_2D (Render image from Android player to Unity texture) and currently do it through read pixels from buffer with attached source texture. This process work correctly on my OnePlus 5 phone, but have some glitches with image on phones like xiaomi note 4, mi a2 and etc (like image is very green), and also there is perfomance issues becouse of this process works every frame and than more pixels to read, than worser perfomance (even my phone has low fps at 4k resolution). Any idea how to optimize this process or do it in some other way?

Thanks and best regards!

```
GLuint FramebufferName;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, g_ExtTexturePointer, 0);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    LOGD("%s", "Error: Could not setup frame buffer.");
}

unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[g_SourceWidth * g_SourceHeight * 4];
glReadPixels(0, 0, g_SourceWidth, g_SourceHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_TexturePointer);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, g_SourceWidth, g_SourceHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

delete[] data;
```

**UPDATE.** 
Function which contain this code and function which calls it from Unity side

```
static void UNITY_INTERFACE_API OnRenderEvent(int eventID) { ... }

extern "C" UnityRenderingEvent UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API UMDGetRenderEventFunc()
{
    return OnRenderEvent;
}
```

Which called from Unity Update function like this:

```
[DllImport("RenderingPlugin")]
static extern IntPtr UMDGetRenderEventFunc();

IEnumerator UpdateVideoTexture()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ...
        androidPlugin.UpdateSurfaceTexture();
        GL.IssuePluginEvent(UMDGetRenderEventFunc, 1);
    } 
}
```

And Android plugin do this on its side (surfaceTexture its texture which contain this external texture on which ExoPlayer render video)

```
public void exportUpdateSurfaceTexture() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (this.mIsStopped) {
            return;
        }
        surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the function that's calling the code above. Also, post the C# side of the code too.

Comment: @Programmer I'm added more information about this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On the C++ side:**

You're creating and destroying pixel data every frame when you do `new unsigned char[g_SourceWidth * g_SourceHeight * 4];` and `delete[] data`  and that's expensive depending on the Texture size. Create the texture data once then re-use it.

One way to do this is to have `static` variables on the C++ side hold the texture information then a function to initialize those variables::

```
static void* pixelData = nullptr;
static int _x;
static int _y;
static int _width;
static int _height;

void initPixelData(void* buffer, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    pixelData = buffer;
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
}
```

Then your capture function should be re-written to remove `new unsigned char[g_SourceWidth * g_SourceHeight * 4];` and `delete[] data` but use the static variables.

```
static void UNITY_INTERFACE_API OnRenderEvent(int eventID)
{
    if (pixelData == nullptr) {
        //Debug::Log("Pointer is null", Color::Red);
        return;
    }

    GLuint FramebufferName;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, g_ExtTexturePointer, 0);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        LOGD("%s", "Error: Could not setup frame buffer.");
    }

    glReadPixels(_x, _y, _width, _height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_TexturePointer);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _width, _height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData);

    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

extern "C" UnityRenderingEvent UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API
UMDGetRenderEventFunc()
{
    return OnRenderEvent;
}
```

**On the C# side:**

```
[DllImport("RenderingPlugin", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void initPixelData(IntPtr buffer, int x, int y, int width, int height);

[DllImport("RenderingPlugin", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr UMDGetRenderEventFunc();
```

Create the Texture information, pin it and send the pointer to C++:

```
int width = 500;
int height = 500;

//Where Pixel data will be saved
byte[] screenData;
//Where handle that pins the Pixel data will stay
GCHandle pinHandler;

//Used to test the color
public RawImage rawImageColor;
private Texture2D texture;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake()
{
    Resolution res = Screen.currentResolution;
    width = res.width;
    height = res.height;

    //Allocate array to be used
    screenData = new byte[width * height * 4];
    texture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);

    //Pin the Array so that it doesn't move around
    pinHandler = GCHandle.Alloc(screenData, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    //Register the screenshot and pass the array that will receive the pixels
    IntPtr arrayPtr = pinHandler.AddrOfPinnedObject();

    initPixelData(arrayPtr, 0, 0, width, height);

    StartCoroutine(UpdateVideoTexture());
}
```

Then to update the texture, see the sample below. Note that there are two methods to update the texture as shown on the code below. If you run into issues with Method1, *comment out* the two lines which uses `texture.LoadRawTextureData` and `texture.Apply` and *un-comment* the Method2 code which uses the `ByteArrayToColor`, `texture.SetPixels` and `texture.Apply` function:

```
IEnumerator UpdateVideoTexture()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Take screenshot of the screen
        GL.IssuePluginEvent(UMDGetRenderEventFunc(), 1);

        //Update Texture Method1
        texture.LoadRawTextureData(screenData);
        texture.Apply();

        //Update Texture Method2. Use this if the Method1 above crashes
        /*
        ByteArrayToColor();
        texture.SetPixels(colors);
        texture.Apply();
        */

        //Test it by assigning the texture to a raw image
        rawImageColor.texture = texture;

        //Wait for a frame
        yield return null;
    }
}

Color[] colors = null;

void ByteArrayToColor()
{
    if (colors == null)
    {
        colors = new Color[screenData.Length / 4];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < screenData.Length; i += 4)
    {
        colors[i / 4] = new Color(screenData[i],
            screenData[i + 1],
            screenData[i + 2],
            screenData[i + 3]);
    }
}
```

Unpin the array when done or when the script is about to be destroyed:

```
void OnDisable()
{
    //Unpin the array when disabled
    pinHandler.Free();
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for full answer with clarification, I gonna check it in few hours! The only thing (which I clearly doesn't mention before, my bad) is - this data what I read from Android player it's dash streaming video and it can change resolution in any time depending on internet connection, this is why I always reinit array with g_Source width and height.

Comment: If resolution can change, add a callback function to the C# side that you can call to resize the array on the C# side if the width and height don't match anymore then free the current handler with `pinHandler.Free()`, resize the array, the texture size, pin the new array again with `pinHandler = GCHandle.Alloc(screenData, GCHandleType.Pinned)` get the address again with `pinHandler.AddrOfPinnedObject()` and update the information on the C++ side by calling the `initPixelData` function. You're basically re-doing what you did before in the `Awake` function.

Comment: Thanks! It became better, but still not enough for 4k resolution even on OnePlus 5) Maybe you know why this kind of bug with image can showed up? It happens not on all phones, but still [link](https://i.imgur.com/wpJM9ym.jpg)

Comment: Where are you getting the video texture and does the image you linked happen every frame or once in while?

Comment: I found out that this effect exists only on Xiaomi phones (check four different Xiaomi models), but razer and OnePlus is ok. I link videotexture from exoplayer (android) with g_exttexturepointer only once at start and after that only everything you saw in code. Update this texture at android side and after this update in Unity.

Comment: It's really hard to help since another API is involved. Maybe there is something wrong with Exoplayer on Xiaomi phones. I don't have Xiaomi device to test either

Comment: The bug looks to be because the readback doesn't convert the YUV data from the camera into RGB correctly. Looks like a bug in the Adreno drivers (although I suspect you're skating close to the edge of what is expected to work).

Comment: @solidpixel I read before some topics on stackoverflow  about this. But thought that if it correctly work on all other devices (Google, lg, razer, Nokia and etc.) It's not my case. Maybe I missed something and there is some difference with them?

Comment: @Programmer any idea why you can attach the framebuffer to an external texture? according to the khronos manual the external texture target isn't an option: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture2D.xml

Comment: whenever I try to attach my framebuffer to the external texture from a surfacetexture it crashes with a `Framebuffer not complete, status=36055`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `glReadPixels` is always going to be slow; CPUs are not good at bulk data transfer.

Ideally you'd managed to convince Unity to accept an external image handle, and do the whole process zero copy, but failing that I would use a GPU render-to-texture and use a shader to transfer from the external image to the RGB surface.

Comment: Not so long ago found some information about pixel buffer and reading from it, but never test it. Maybe you have some experience with it?

Comment: You can use a pbuffer to do asynchronous `glReadPixels`, but it's still going to be horribly slow. As I said, CPUs are not designed for fast bulk data transfer. Use the GPU, it's what it's exceptionally good at ...