# Rendering from GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES to GL_TEXTURE_2D but only one color flashes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, vlc

I'm pretty new to opengl-es and currently have a problem rendering my video output on a screen in Unity.

I was developing a video player project with Unity. I bought the EasyMovieTexture plugin and replaced the video player module with another open-source video player (Ijkplayer) years ago which worked fine all the time.

Now I want to replace it with newer VLC using libvlcjni. I compiled and just replaced the old Ijkplayer but it didn't work as I expected. The screen just started flashing one color from every video frame but the video was going and the audio track was normally playing too.

[Screenshot - A test scene with a screen, sorry there's mistake with texcoord but only color flashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGNMX.jpg)

I'd like to provide some further information hope that I can find some help (Sorry if I have some mistakes or misunderstandings):

1. As far as I know, these video player modules need a `Surface` (Or `SurfaceTexture`) in the Android layer and the video decoder will work as a data producer. The `SurfaceTexture` consumes data from the producer and converts it to the texture with the type of `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` which can be directly consumed and displayed with components like `TextureView`. But this texture data cannot be consumed in the Unity layer **unless I use a GLSL shader directly sampling my OES texture data**, like this:

   ```c
   // Unity shader with GLSL
   GLSLPROGRAM
       #pragma only_renderers gles3
       #include "UnityCG.glslinc"
   // ...
   // Ignoring vertex shader
   // ...
       in vec2 textureCoord;
       layout(binding = 0) uniform samplerExternalOES _MainTex;
       out vec4 fragColor;
       void main()
       {
           fragColor  = texture(_MainTex, textureCoord);
       }
   ENDGLSL
   ```
2. My approach was to convert the texture to `GL_TEXTURE_2D` with the native library which came along with the EasyMovieTexture plugin. Here I cannot provide the source code of this `.so` library but I've decompiled it in IDAPro and I know it can work along with GLES and render the external texture data to another 2d texture using FrameBuffer Object and external shader program.

   - Here is a random example to explain the procedure, it is **NOT** the accurate code from the binary: [FilterFBOTexture.java](https://github.com/hywenbinger/EasyMovie-Android/blob/master/videoplugin_opengles3/src/main/java/com/pvr/videoplugin/FilterFBOTexture.java)
   - Though I cannot edit the `.so` file, luckily it was reading two external files as the shader program:

   ```c
   // vertex shader
   attribute highp   vec3  inVertex;
   attribute mediump vec3  inNormal;
   attribute mediump vec2  inTexCoord;
   uniform highp   mat4  MVPMatrix;
   uniform mediump vec2 TexCoordMove;
   varying mediump vec2   TexCoord;

   void main()
   {
       highp vec4 vPos = vec4(0,0,0,1);

       vPos.x = ( inTexCoord.x * 2.0 - 1.0 );
       vPos.y = ( inTexCoord.y * 2.0 - 1.0 );

       gl_Position = vPos;

       mediump vec4 vec4Temp  = vec4(inTexCoord.x - TexCoordMove.x,inTexCoord.y - TexCoordMove.y,0,1.0);
       vec4Temp  = MVPMatrix * vec4Temp;
       vec4Temp.xyz = vec4Temp.xyz / vec4Temp.w;
       TexCoord = vec4Temp.xy;
   }
   ```

   ```c
   // fragment shader
   #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
   uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
   uniform lowp float AlphaValue;
   varying mediump vec2  TexCoord;
   void main()
   {
       lowp vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, TexCoord) ;
       color = vec4(color.rgb, color.a * AlphaValue);
       gl_FragColor = color;
   }
   ```

I don't know whether I have to check the vertex shader or just dive into the source code of libvlcjni so that I can correctly render my video output. Any idea will be grateful, thanks.

**Update 2022-11-4:**

I turned around and began to use VLC for Android.

Big appreciation to @mfkl, I created an issue days ago on the VLC repo.

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-unity/-/issues/164

The problem still remains but at least I can work for something now.

Comment: Can you successfully render the converted GL_TEXTURE_2D in android?

Comment: @shingo I think the answer is no, sorry I'm also new to android too and at least I didn't develop any pure Android program before. I just tested with a TextureView component and it worked fine with VLC. But when I was setting a new SurfaceTexture object to the TextureView or GLSurfaceView, it did not even show the color and only the audio track playing.

Comment: I've tried converting texture to GL_TEXTURE_2D with only GLES30 API but didn't succeed. And It was difficult to debug my aar plugin in Unity program.

Comment: @shingo is it better to try and confirm whether I can render the converted GL_TEXTURE_2D in android? In fact, I've read many articles and tried for over 2 weeks now. Sadly I cannot stick to this question cause I have too much to learn about opengl-es, android or vlc and also I have some other tasks to deal with :P

Comment: This looks like a conversion issue. My opinion 1) Yes, try to test the converted texture in android first. 2) Start with a simplest shader.

Comment: @shingo thanks. I will try to figure that out first.

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-unity

Comment: @mfkl yes I‘ve learned about the repositories provided by VideoLAN official. The earlier one was built for the standalone platform and recently there is also a solution for android. But I checked the package content and the plugin called "libVLCUnityPlugin" is a black box which means I may not have enough flexibility to fix or modify my video plugin cause the plugin is not open-source.

Comment: Also in the unity assets store, these plugin packages are sold for $100

Comment: The plugin is fully opensource, there is no blackbox.

Comment: @mfkl sorry and yes, I see the plugin source for video rendering. But I don't know the difference between the open-source repo and the asset in the unity store. Is technical support the only difference between these options?

Comment: please take a look on that question for anyone having the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561796/allow-for-multiple-pass-renders-in-glsurfaceview-renderer-with-surfacetexture
I have started a bounty there